# As3 Error 5000 on class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

So I tried to class an as3.file with my .fla (via QuickKong)

This error occurred:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 4   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 11  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 18  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 25  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 32  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 39  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 46  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 53  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 59  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 67  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 74  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 81  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 88  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 95  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 102 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 108 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
**C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\To A Million\QuickKong.as, Line 1 5000: The class 'QuickKong' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.**
```

Then I import: `import flash.events.MouseEvent;`

The error became this.

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 8   1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 15  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 22  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 29  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 36  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 43  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 50  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 57  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 63  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 71  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 78  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 85  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 92  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 99  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 106 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 112 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method play.
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\To A Million\QuickKong.as, Line 1   1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addFrameScript.
Scene 1, Layer 'menu', Frame 2, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 4, Line 1   1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 27, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 27, Line 2  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndPlay.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 28, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 29, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 30, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 31, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 32, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 33, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 34, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 35, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 36, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 37, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 38, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 39, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 40, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 41, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 42, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 43, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 4', Frame 44, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
**C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\To A Million\QuickKong.as, Line 1 5000: The class 'QuickKong' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.**
```

How do I interpret and fix this error? I have path to the file. The `.fla` has recogonized the file within the `fla`.

[The AS File](http://profusiongames.com/downloads/QuickKong/QuickKong.as)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
```

and change public class into this:

```
public class QuickKong extends MovieClip
```

Comment: public class QuickKong extends MovieClip

Comment: It adds an extra error  C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\To A Million\QuickKong.as, Line 1 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addFrameScript.

Comment: Connecting to Kong with the as3. The as3 is essential to connect to Kong